# Delete multplie JSON keys using Eloquent or raw statement

Tags: laravel

I have stored a JSON array in my contacts table, and are able to run a statement to remove a key using my SQL manager, but i haven´t found any way to translate this query to Eloquent or a raw statement:

```
UPDATE `contacts` SET `additional` = JSON_REMOVE(`additional` , '$."3"')
```

Any ideas how to run this query in Laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
$id = 3;
$jsonPath = '$."'.$id.'"';
```

Using a raw statement

```php
DB::statement('UPDATE contacts SET additional = JSON_REMOVE(additional, ?)', [$jsonPath];
```

Using QueryBuilder:

```php
DB::table('contacts')
    ->update([
        'additional' => DB::raw("JSON_REMOVE(additional, '$jsonPath')")
    ]);
```

Using Eloquent:

```php
Contact::query()
    ->update([
        'additional' => DB::raw("JSON_REMOVE(additional, '$jsonPath')")
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks, works great, but do you have any ideas how to pass a variable (replace "3" with $id)?

Comment: Found the solution: Contact::query()->update(['additional' => DB::raw('JSON_REMOVE(additional , \'$\.\"' . $id . '\"\')')]);